# githubActions : how display a test coverage?

Tags: github, github-actions

I use github actions. 
My gradle project use jacoco to produce a test coverage report, on the form of a website.
How can I display it directly on the browser ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually when JaCoCo builds report in html format it produces a bunch of files and folders. So, there is no possibility to open that main html file directly in your browser. But here are possible solutions that might be useful for you:

- Publish generated static files on some server, like GitHub Pages for
  example. Where you can see generated report in a website mode (you
  can configure notification with the link when published report is
  ready).
- Archive generated report and upload it as artifact. Then you
  can easily find each report for each job if needed.
- Build report as xml and just print it in output window.
- Archive generated report and send it to some your running server.

Based on your needs maybe you find some of these suggestions useful but probably first option only directly answers your question.